# how to enable time series data in flot chart?

Tags: time-series, flot

[Flot documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) says that it is based on javascript timestamp.

I have tried to convert my `JSON` to comply this standard, and my JSON looks like this

```
{"label":"Activation","data": [
         ["1382061194000","10"],["1382061195000","9"],["1382061196000","9"],
         ["1382061197000","20"],["1382061198000","6"],["1382061203000","16"],
         ["1382061204000","12"],["1382061205000","14"],["1382061206000","22"],
         ["1382061207000","20"],["1382061208000","10"],["1382061209000","19"],
         ["1382061210000","13"],["1382061211000","9"],["1382061212000","12"],
         ["1382061214000","12"],["1382061215000","17"],["1382061216000","6"],
         ["1382061217000","14"],["1382061218000","22"],["1382061219000","43"],
         ["1382061220000","34"],["1382061221000","27"],["1382061222000","31"],
         ["1382061223000","2"],["1382061224000","1"],["1382061225000","86"],
         ["1382061226000","82"],["1382061227000","4"],["1382061228000","7"],
         ["1382061229000","6"],["1382061230000","18"],["1382061231000","17"],
         ["1382061232000","15"],["1382061233000","3"],["1382061234000","14"],
         ["1382061235000","2"],["1382061236000","8"],["1382061237000","14"],
         ["1382061238000","9"],["1382061239000","5"]
]}
```

And i setup flot options like this

```
xaxis: {tickSize: 1,mode: "time", timeformat: "%H:%M:%S"}
```

The chart never up :(

Well actually the goal is simple, I just want to show a flot chart with `08:02:30` `08:02:31` as the xaxis info. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're passing in your dates as strings.

```
> new Date("1382061194000")
Invalid Date
> new Date(1382061194000)
Thu Oct 17 2013 21:53:14 GMT-0400 (EDT)
```

Try removing the quotes (around your data points too) and see what that does.